# Showing a function does not have two distinct roots

Tags: analysis, roots

I have the function $f(x)=x^3-(3/2)x^2+k$ where $k$ is any real number and I am to show that the function does not have two distinct roots in the interval $[0,1]$.

I am in need of help applying the mean value theorem and rolle's theorem to prove this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: What sign does its derivative have over the interior of that interval?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $f$ has two distinct roots $a$ and $b$ in the unit interval (say $b>a$). Then by the mean value theorem $$0=f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)=(3c^2-3c)(b-a)$$

for some $c\in(0,1)$. But does the derivative vanish in $(0,1)$?

Comment: Hi, I might be confused but should the equation read 0=f(b)−f(a)=... instead of 0=f(a)-f(b)

Comment: I elaborated and fixed it.

Comment: thanks. I am new to this topic so forgive my confusion. I'm not sure what you mean when you say does the derivative vanish

Comment: i'm not sure what the next step would be